# Display certain number of characters from a input String

Tags: java

I need to be able to display a certain number of characters from a `String` (say 20 characters max), where the input String could be from 0,1 to very long text, but I just need to display a certain number of characters.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: use substring method of String class, like String s = "asdakldhkahdkajdakldkladklasldalksdhlasjdalsldl"; s.o.p(s.substring(0,19));

Comment: The current code you're using, gets the entire string if the size is less than 10. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache's `StringUtils` class has a method for this.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

StringUtils.left(theString,20);
```

It's safe to use if `theString` is null, or is shorter than 20 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Write a small method and return the string to show

```
 public static String getStringToShow(String str) {

        if (str.length() < 20) {

            return str;
        } else {

            return str.substring(0, 20);
        }
    }
```

Then

```
lable.setText(getStringToShow(Actualstr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to printing out a sub string of an original string. You'd do this by using the `substring()` method.

```
String text = "blah blah blah this is a string";
System.out.println(text.substring(0,6));
```

Where 0 is the starting index and 6 is the end index.
yields the following output:

`blah b`

**EDIT**

In response to your update:

you can check the length of your string before finding a substring:

```
String text = "blah blah blah this is a string";
if(text.length() < 20)
    System.out.println(text);
else
    System.out.println(text.substring(0,20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the way you are doing this at the moment is the most concise way of doing it ... modulo that 10 is not 20.

You might just want to turn that into a "helper" method if you are going to perform this operation in lots of places in your code.